# How to notify more than one person in a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

How to notify more than one person in a comment? It would be really handy if we could notify more than one person in a comment. Many times it is needed that 2 or 3 persons be named but, as that is not possibility, I have to repeat the comment.

Comment: You can't. You have to repeat the comment.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: @Richard Booooo! (throws rotten tomatoes)

Comment: @BlackandWhite - Don't hate me because I'm always right

Comment: @Richard I was only joking! ;)

Answer (score 4):

As [Richard has commented](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10658/how-to-notify-more-than-one-person-in-a-comment#comment43804_10658), you can't explicitly reference more than one person in a comment.

However, the person whose post you are commenting on always gets notified, so if they are one of the intended recipients, that's good. Just include another intended recipient too.

The reason for this restriction is that **comments are not for discussion.** They are simply notifications or requests for clarification. There should never be any need for more than one person to be notified of a comment; and certainly no need for more than one person in addition to the poster to be notified.

If you ever feel that the existing @-notification mechanism is insufficient, **you're doing it wrong.** Include the poster and perhaps the most useful other recipient (if there is one) and leave it at that.

Comment: Basically, if you want to talk to multiple people, seriously consider starting a chat room. It'll save mods moving stuff into the chat later anyway...

Comment: @marcellothearcane Yes. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: You may also want to mention that (in certain cases whose exact definition I have yet to figure out) anyone who has previously commented on the post will also be notified.

Comment: @Janus I didn't realise that happened. Perhaps the system does that when it can't determine (by some method possibly including textual analysis) who should be notified.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I find myself having to repeat a comment to more than one user. Of course, the post's owner is notified, but since my comment is towards two users, I'd follow the following style.

> [Here's my comment to the OP.]
>
> ---
>
> @User1 [Here's my comment to user1]
>
> ---
>
> (cc: @User2) Please see [my comment above].

Comments are not for discussion, but it is sometimes found necessary to communicate something with two users usually other than the OP.

Comment: Agree.  And this isn't necessarily starting a discussion.  When or if it does, then go to chat.

Comment: "Above" can be problematic with comments. Why not include [a link to the comment like this one to ab2's comment](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10658/how-to-notify-more-than-one-person-in-a-comment#comment43823_10663)? just click the time stamp.

Comment: Sure. Links would be helpful as well. @ColleenV